# Mod_Qos Rule To Limit GET Requests From Same IP?

Tags: apache-2.2

I receive about 50 GET requests from a single IP

To avoid any server slowdown, I installed Mod_Qos and added this rule:

```
QS_LocRequestLimit /home/user/public_html/folder/ 20
QS_LocRequestLimitMatch       "^(/home/user/public_html/folder/).*$" 10
```

This does not seem to limit the GET requests, what is it that I am doing wrong? On Server Status I actually see that Mod_QOS applied the rules successfully, but it does not seem to correctly track concurrent requests to that folder

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the file system path to the resource in your config file. You need to replace that with the actual URI used in the GET request - in this instance, I'd guess that it's `~user/folder`.